# ASP.NET url redirect without child

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
<rule name="news_en">
   <match url="en/news/"/>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="en/blog/NewsList.aspx"/>
</rule>
```

It redirects too if url looks like [...]/en/news/id1234; but I don't need that. What should I do?

Comment: You could set the following attribute on the rule  `patternSyntax="ExactMatch"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <rule name="news_en">
      <match url="^en/news/$"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="en/blog/NewsList.aspx"/>
    </rule>
```

`^` means matching will start from the begin of the domain name.
So `www.yourdomain.com/en/news/` will redirect while `www.yourdomain.com/pages/en/news/` will not.

`$` nothing is allowed behind the matched string.

Answer (score 1):

Use "en/news$" as a match url to match ../en/news and "en/news/$" to match ../en/news/ .